# what is in the electrostatic field that makes the word done independent of path taken?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, electrostatics

I am trying to understand how is it possible for electric force to behave like this (path independence)?

I am repeatedly failing to get an intuitive meaning behind its (electric field) nature of doing the work.

Does it have to do with the radial direction of electric force ? or Its inverse-square law nature?

Comment: @danu:  I accept it as conservative. I only want to know how the electric field is conservative?

Comment: Do you understand it for the gravitational field?

Answer (score 1):

You can show for a point charge that the curl of the electrostatic field vanishes: $\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{E}=0$. Since all charge distributions can be obtained by integrating over point charges, we can say that the electrostatic field in general has zero curl.

This implies that it can be written as the gradient of a scalar: $\vec{E}=-\vec{\nabla}V$ for some suitable scalar V. This, in turn, implies that $$\int_a^b\vec{E}\cdot\mbox{d}\vec{l}=-\int_a^b\vec{\nabla}V\cdot\mbox{d}\vec{l}=V(\vec{a})-V(\vec{b})$$ by the fundamental theorem for gradients. Now you see, this expression only depends on the end points, not the path.

Comment: It is too equational for me to understand. 

Here is my guess from your equations:

Is it the radial outward nature of electrostatic force from a point charge responsible for this conservativeness?

Comment: The curl vanishes because it is radially outward, yes. I don't find it very satisfying, however, to posit that this is the reason $\vec{E}$ is conservative. Anyways, if you're not comfortable with this level of 'equational', you may want to get some more practice in calculus.